# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when using express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am having an issue that I can't understand. I have wrote code following this same structure before and never had this problem so I am really struggling to understand what is going on here.

I have these 3 files:

index.ts

```
import { Controller } from "./controller";
import express from "express";

const app = express();

const controller = new Controller();

app.use("/api", controller.router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening"));
```

controller.ts

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { Service } from "./service";

export class Controller {
  router = Router();

  private service = new Service();

  constructor() {
    this.router.get("/all", this.getAll);
  }

  getAll() {
    console.log("getAll");

    this.service.findAll(); // problem here
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
export class Service {
  findAll() {
    console.log("findAll");
  }
}
```

If I try to call `controller.getAll()` on `index.ts` everything goes as expected: function getAll() is called, then findAll() is called inside of getAll().

The problem is when I try to do a GET request to `localhost:3000/api/all` getAll() is called normally but when `this.service.findAll()` is reached the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'service')
    at getAll (/home/user/personal/test/src/controller.ts:16:22)
```

dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the line binding getAll to the route. Passing `this.getAll` ends up causing issues with context for the `this` reference. This is what's causing the error you see, where `this` is undefined.

A simple way to solve the issue is to declare an inline arrow function, like below.

```js
  constructor() {
    this.router.get("/all", () => this.getAll());
  }
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)